# 13.04 + Gnome 3.8 integrated input methods now working

Tags: gnome, 13.04, keyboard-layout, ibus

It was stated that in gnome-shell 3.8+ was released integrated input method where i would not need to take care of setting up iBus and deal with enabling/disabling it every time.

Since i always use 3 languages one of which requires iBus i decided to give it a try in VirtualBox. So i've installed latest stable Ubuntu GNOME (13.04), added PPA for Gnome and did `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`.

But seems that this announced feature doesn't work. I added needed languages and indicator-applet shows that i switch between them, but language requiring iBus (Chinese in this case) still uses standard layout and all i enter is just Roman characters.

Is there anything I am missing or have done wrong?

Comment: have you tried ibus-setup?

Answer (score 0):

Try also adding the gnome3 staging ppa as well  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging`

and full update

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: That doesn't help eeither